# sklearn TfidfVectorizer : How to make few words to only be part of bi gram in the features

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

I want the featurization of `TfidfVectorizer` to consider some predefined words such as `"script", "rule",` only to be used in bigrams.

If I have text `"Script include is a script that has rule which has a business rule"`

for the above text if I use

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2),stop_words='english')
```

I should get

```
['script include','business rule','include','business']
```

Comment: why is not 'include script' not in your output because in 'include is a script' 'is a' are stop words and you are removing the stopwords. Can you please clarify

Answer (score 4):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import text 
# Given a vocabulary returns a filtered vocab which
# contain only tokens in include_list and which are 
# not stop words
def filter_vocab(full_vocab, include_list):
    b_list = list()
    for x in full_vocab:
        add = False
        for t in x.split():
            if t in text.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS:
                add = False
                break
            if t in include_list:
                add = True
        if add:
            b_list.append(x)
    return b_list

# Get all the ngrams (one can also use nltk.util.ngram)
ngrams = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2), norm=None, smooth_idf=False, use_idf=False)
X = ngrams.fit_transform(["Script include is a script that has rule which has a business rule"])
full_vocab = ngrams.get_feature_names()

# filter the full ngram based vocab
filtered_v = filter_vocab(full_vocab,["include", "business"])

# Get tfidf using the new filtere vocab
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2), vocabulary=filtered_v)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(["Script include is a script that has rule which has a business rule"])
v = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
print (v)
```

***Code is commented to explain what it is doing***

Comment: Not exactly what I want.. But gave me a direction.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are looking for customizing the n_grams creation based upon your special words (I call it as `interested_words` in the function). I have customized the default [n_grams creation function](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e9/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L149) for your purpose.

```
def custom_word_ngrams(tokens, stop_words=None, interested_words=None):
    """Turn tokens into a sequence of n-grams after stop words filtering"""

    original_tokens = tokens
    stop_wrds_inds = np.where(np.isin(tokens,stop_words))[0]
    intersted_wrds_inds = np.where(np.isin(tokens,interested_words))[0]

    tokens = [w for w in tokens if w not in stop_words+interested_words] 

    n_original_tokens = len(original_tokens)

    # bind method outside of loop to reduce overhead
    tokens_append = tokens.append
    space_join = " ".join

    for i in xrange(n_original_tokens - 1):
        if  not any(np.isin(stop_wrds_inds, [i,i+1])):
            tokens_append(space_join(original_tokens[i: i + 2]))

    return tokens
```

Now, we can plugin this function inside the usual [analyzer](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e9/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L323) of TfidfVectorizer, as following!

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.externals.six.moves import xrange
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import  TfidfVectorizer,CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction import  text


def analyzer():
    base_vect = CountVectorizer()
    stop_words = list(text.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS)
    preprocess = base_vect.build_preprocessor()
    tokenize = base_vect.build_tokenizer()

    return lambda doc: custom_word_ngrams(
        tokenize(preprocess(base_vect.decode(doc))), stop_words, ['script', 'rule']) 
    #feed your special words list here

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer=analyzer())
vectorizer.fit(["Script include is a script that has rule which has a business rule"])
vectorizer.get_feature_names()
```

> ['business', 'business rule', 'include', 'script include']

Answer (score -1):

`TfidfVectorizer` allows you to provide your own tokenizer, you can do something like below. But you will lose other words information in vocabulary.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
corpus = ["Script include is a script that has rule which has a business rule"]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2),tokenizer=lambda corpus: [ "script", "rule"],stop_words='english')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```