# Sklearn - toggling tf-idf to register two-word phrases

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm experimenting with the text analysis tools in sklearn, namely the LDA topic extraction algorithm seen [here](https://scikit-learn.org/0.18/auto_examples/applications/topics_extraction_with_nmf_lda.html).

I've tried feeding it other data sets and in some cases I think I would get better topic extraction results if the vector representation of the tf-idf 'features' could allow for phrases.

As an easy example:

I often get top word associations like:

- income
- net
- asset
- fixed
- wealth
- fiscal

Which is understandable, but I think that I won't get the granularity I need for a useful topic extraction unless the `TfidfVectorizer()` or some other parameter can be tweaked such that I get phrases. Ideally, I want:

- fixed income
- asset management
- wealth management
- net income
- fiscal income

To make things simple, I'm imagining I supply the algorithm with a white list of tolerable 2-word phrases. It would count only those phrases as unique while applying normal tf-idf weighting to all other word entries throughout the corpus.

### Question

The documentation for `TfidfVectorizer()` doesn't seem to support this, but I'd imagine this is a fairly common need in practice -- so how do practitioners go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default configuration `TfidfVectorizer` is using an `ngram_range=(1,1)`, this means that it will only use unigram (single word).

You can change this parameter to `ngram_range(1,2)` in order to retrieve bigram as well as unigram and if your bigrams are sufficiently represented they will be extracted as well.

See example below:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
corpus = [
    'This is the first document.',
    'This document is the second document.',
    'And this is the third one.',
    'Is this the first document?',
]
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1))
print(f'output with ngram_range=(1,1): {tfidf.fit(corpus).get_feature_names()}\n')

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2))
print(f'output with ngram_range=(1,2): {tfidf.fit(corpus).get_feature_names()}')
```

Outpout:

```
output with ngram_range=(1,1): ['and', 'document', 'first', 'is', 'one', 'second', 'the', 'third', 'this']

output with ngram_range=(1,2): ['and', 'and this', 'document', 'document is', 'first', 'first document', 'is', 'is the', 'is this', 'one', 'second', 'second document', 'the', 'the first', 'the second', 'the third', 'third', 'third one', 'this', 'this document', 'this is', 'this the']
```

Comment: Guess this was stupidity on my part. Never knew what an 'n-gram' was. Still wish documentation was written without so much jargon.

Comment: And would still be interested to see results based on a custom, user-provided phrase list as opposed to a blanket adjustment of n-grams.

Comment: Yes, documentation is really technical with a lot of precise terms :). Concerning your second comment, you might be able to do it using this answer on SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/55163111/4574633. (In my opinion, it is better to have an approach based on the data and frequencies of the word rather than user input)